# MySQL get only numbers from result

Tags: mysql

I have some data that looks like below. `KOPOF-ORT2` is always 20 `chars` long. I want to extract the 3 last characters if they are a number.

```
| KOPOF-ORT2           | Minimum |
|----------------------|---------|
| SE 10-19,60-61,  652 | 652     |
| SE 20-28,29      476 | 476     |
| IT 33 VILLANUOVA DI  | DI      |
```

Desired result:

```
| KOPOF-ORT2           | Minimum |
|----------------------|---------|
| SE 10-19,60-61,  652 | 652     |
| SE 20-28,29      476 | 476     |
| IT 33 VILLANUOVA DI  |         |
```

I have tried something likes this

```
SELECT KOPOF-ORT2, IF(substr(KOPOF-ORT2,18,3) REGEXP '^[0-9]+$', 
substr(KOPOF-ORT2,18,3), '') AS Minimum FROM,,.
```

But is seems like it is not accepting `REGEXP` in the `IF` statement. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to do it in your application code.  What language are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using a REGEX that only matches numbers, so that you don't require an IF statement at all?

Comment: @dmikester1 Yes I know but I just wanted to see if it was possible to do in SQL first.

Comment: @ESmith you mean to add it like `WHERE substr(KOPOF-ORT2,18,3) REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`? Then I guess would miss the entry with `IT 33 VILLANUOVA DI`.

Comment: @g3blv No, use the REGEX_SUBSTR in the select clause so that you either get the numbers or NULL.

Comment: @ESmith Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using REGEX_SUBSTR in your SELECT clause so that it returns either the numbers you'd like or NULL.

(you can paste your solution as a comment below for others to find)

Comment: This is the solution I used `SELECT KOPOF-ORT2, REGEXP_SUBSTR(substr("KOPOF-ORT2",18,3), '^[0-9]+$') AS Minimum FROM,,.`

Comment: Great!  Please mark the answer as correct so that this question shows as 'answered.'